# Why can I not pass a SafeHandle implementation to specific pinvoke functions

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to replace any handles that I use with my pinvoke code with implementations of `SafeHandles`

In particular I created an implementation for a SafeThreadHandle like this

```
internal class SafeThreadHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    internal SafeThreadHandle() : base(true) {}

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return CloseHandle(handle);
    }
}
```

This works great for most cases for example

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern int ResumeThread(SafeThreadHandle threadHandle);
```

When I try to use a`SafeThreadHandle` as a parameter for the following two pinvoke functions, the function fails and sets a windows error of 998 which msdn states is the following

> ERROR_NOACCESS
>   998 (0x3E6)
>   Invalid access to memory location.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern bool GetThreadContext(SafeThreadHandle threadHandle, ref Context64 context);


[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern bool SetThreadContext(SafeThreadHandle threadHandle, ref Context64 context);
```

The weird thing is, if I replace the SafeThreadHandle with an IntPtr (the parameter and argument) to the thread handle that is gotten through `threadHandle.GetDangerousHandle()`, the functions succeed and work as they are supposed to.

So I guess my question is why can I not use my `SafeThreadHandle` implementation of a `SafeHandle` as a parameter to the above two functions, but I can use it for other functions such as `ResumeThread`

Comment: When do you call SetHandle? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/microsoft/win32/safehandles/SafeThreadHandle.cs

Comment: I'm getting the handle using OpenThread (which returns a SafeThreadHandle) and I read that Marshal handles that hence the parameterless constructor

Comment: I don't reproduce the problem. It could be due to the Context64 parameter definition and/or calling. Also, how can you tell the error if you don't define SetLastError on GetThreadContext. Please share a full .zip repro somewhere.

Comment: Sorry I excluded the SetLastError from the examples provided as I typed them out before I started debugging but I'm using it in my real code. It's a bit hard to provide the project because its quite large. Would it be possible for you to share the code you used? I'll post a reply after I've compared the two sources and let you know If I had any differences.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/5ACMPh2N

Comment: Whilst your way seems to work (no failure), when I read the structure (Context) from the pointer, the values in the structure are incorrect. I'm double checked my structures and even copy pasted the ones from stack overflow and I still got incorrect values.

Comment: Your question is about SafeHandles and p/invoke, not about GetThreadContext. Before calling GetThreadContext you must set the ContextFlags properly. My code doesn't do that so it returns almost nothing, this is expected.

Comment: I see thankyou for the help

Answer (score 1):

So after much testing and help from Simon, I managed to deduce the issue down to referencing the Context structs in the pinvoke function.

For some reason, I could not use my `SafeThreadHandle` as a parameter if I was using a ref.

So the solution was to make the following change

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern bool GetThreadContext(SafeThreadHandle threadHandle, IntPtr context);
```

And then marshal the struct from the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Context64 isn't defined correctly.
Try working implementations:

https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetThreadContext
https://github.com/dahall/Vanara/blob/3e1596ba7f60f6478e9efd0d5c1b30d102df9439/PInvoke/Kernel32/ProcessThreadsApi.cs#L3291